# Android Studio problem with Code > Override Methods

Tags: android, android-studio, overriding

I have a problem with some functionalities in Android Studio. I am doing the "Android Kotlin Fundamentals" tutorial right now and I am supposed to use the in-built functionality of "Code > Override Methods" more often now.

When I open one of the starter-apps used in this tutorial I just can't get it to work. For example pressing CTRL+O in the "MainActivity.kt" does not open the "Override Methods" window, also the way over the menu with Code > Override Methods does not work.

Only when I create an activity myself the window opens when I press the hotkey. So I think this is maybe a permission problem? (I am working with Linux and tried setting permissions for the project folder which resulted in Android Studio not recognizing the folder as Android project).

I already tried searching for this problem, but couldn't find a solution. Maybe here someone can help me.